# Django model's table doesnt contain given field

Tags: python, django

I have the following model in Django:

```
class Priority(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField
```

However, when I run makemigrations and migrate, the field priority ( models.PositiveSmallIntegerField) doesn't appear in mysql table and I cannot create object of this model. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did *not* construct a field, you only passed a reference to that class, you need to add brackets (`()`) to make the call:

```
class Priority(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    #                     call the constructor ^^
```

If you do not call the constructor, you have set `priority` as a reference to the `PositiveSmallIntegerField` *class*, not as a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` object.